# Single query for retrieving a category path

Tags: mysql, recursive

I have the following table structure and content:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| category_id | parent_id |    name    |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
|          1  |        0  | Test 1     |
|          2  |        1  | Test 1.1   |
|          3  |        2  | Test 1.1.1 |
|          4  |        0  | Test 2     |
|          5  |        0  | Test 3     |
|          6  |        5  | Test 3.1   |
|          7  |        6  | Test 3.1.1 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

Is it possible to write a single query that will return the results as following:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------+
| category_id |              path              |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|           1 | Test 1                         |
|           2 | Test 1 > Test 1.1              |
|           3 | Test 1 > Test 1.1 > Test 1.1.1 |
|           4 | Test 2                         |
|           5 | Test 3                         |
|           6 | Test 3 > Test 3.1              |
|           7 | Test 3 > Test 3.1 > Test 3.1.1 |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values in the `name` column are consistent with the `parent_id` values (and the resulting tree), you can use a triangular join and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT 
    t.category_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(anc.name ORDER BY anc.name
                 SEPARATOR ' > ') AS path
FROM tablename AS t                         -- for every row in t
  JOIN tablename AS anc                     -- find its ancestors
    ON t.name LIKE CONCAT(anc.name, '%')
GROUP BY
    t.category_id ;
```

Test in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edd02/2).

Comment: By "consistent" you mean that all the categories should be added in order?

Comment: By consistent I mean that you don't have a row with `category_id=1, name='Test 1'`and another with `parent_id = 1, name='Test 3.7'` That the names (which look like they are storing a materialized path) are consistent with the parent-category values).

Comment: Oh, that's fine, but I think there's a little issue. I've updated the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7389/5) with a few more values. If you run it, you'll notice that "Test 2 > Test 2.1" isn't displayed right afther "Test 2" and same for "Test 3 > Test 3.1 > Test 3.1.1 > Test 3.1.1.1" which should be displayed right after "Test 3 > Test 3.1 > Test 3.1.1". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You mean the order of the results? You can add any `ORDER BY` you want. See for example what happens if you use [`ORDER BY path`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7389/6) (some orderings may be hard to accomplish).

Comment: I tried that already, like `ORDER BY t.parent_id ASC, t.category_id ASC` but the result didn't come out as expected. That's why I asked.

Comment: Did you try `ORDER BY path;` and `ORDER BY t.name;` ?

Comment: I think that just now I understood what you were saying about the consistency. I added "Advertising", then "Outdoor" and then "Flyer" where "Outdoor" is the parent for "Flyer" and "Advertising" is the parent for "Outdoor" and the query didn't work (meaning I don't get the path, I just get each category name on a separate row).

Comment: You mean you replaced all the `"Test"` with different names? That's why it's better to write teh question with some meaningful data in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that's why I did. Will keep this in mind for other questions.

Comment: is it possible to modify the query to match any category name?

Comment: I'll update the answer tomorrow

Comment: Ok. Looking forward for you update. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @ypercube! Can you post the update to your solution? Thank you.

Comment: any chance for updating your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a example to the question, but is similar to the question.

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS' AND t4.name = 'FLASH';
```

Your should read this it might help- http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/